# How to provision multiple Azure VMs with DSC

Tags: azure, dsc

I’m trying to provision multiple Azure VMs using DSC (Desire state configuration). Unfortunately all examples and documentation out there show only simple “one machine” provisioning. I have experimented and research it but still cannot make it work.

By any chance, could somebody point me to example showing how to provision multiple VMs with different configurations?
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? You can use node blocks for multiple machines? You can also use parameters for nodes. Take a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn249925.aspx

Comment: If you're having trouble, post the configuration that you're trying to use against multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure PowerShell cmdlets to create VMs and set DSC configurations on them. Here is a link to an article which describes the same

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/08/05/understanding-azure-vm-dsc-extension/

Comment: We are doing this approach now, but would like to not user cmdlets for creation of VMs. We would like to provision VMs and apply configuration only through DSC.